# Create a maven project with in another java project

Tags: java, maven, heroku, maven-invoker-plugin

As part of small project i need to provide a micro service to create/generate maven based java projects (something similar to [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) but a basic one ).

Since my aim is to just get a maven project, i came across [Maven Invoker](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/) which looks like would serve my purpose. The question that i have is, if i have to host on heroku or aws/gce would it work? I ask because they look like need maven installed on the host where it is deployed , or am i wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want to achieve? Could you give an example?

Comment: I need to do a "archetype:generate" with some pom dependencies, i see that Maven invoker lets me do that, where i can supply custom groupId etc.  Next step once a project is generated is to provide some stub code, quite similar to spring initializr.